# Can I do multiple split sapply operations on a large data frame?

Tags: r, split, aggregate, lapply, sapply

I've been at this for a few hours now, and can't seem to find a solution. I have a very large data frame (upwards of 1.5 million rows), in which I want to do a fairly specific operation. First of all, my data looks like this:

```
STATION       DATE      Precip
COOP 310     -7788        .24
COOP 310     -7788        .15
COOP 310     -6654        .59
COOP 310     -6654        .10
COOP 499     -7122        .64
COOP 499     -7122        .36
COOP 499     -7122        .14
COOP 499     -2350        .11
COOP 499     -2350        .85
```

I have a weatehr station id (STATION), a date in UNIX epoch form (DATE), and precipitation values (15-minute data intervals when it does rain). What I've been trying to do is to determine the daily rainfall sums for each day that it rained per station. The desired output would look something like this:

```
STATION       DATE        24-hour_PRECIP
COOP 310     -7788        0.39
COOP 310     -6654        0.69
COOP 499     -7122        1.14
COOP 499     -2350        0.96
```

This essentially meant, I thought, doing a `SPLIT` operation twice, once to split all data based on identical STATION values, and then again based on identical DATE values. Theoretically, this output would then be run through an `SAPPLY` operation, applying the `SUM` function to the data set in each unique Date/Station set. My approach (although wrong):

Data frame name is "dfhour":

```
sp1<-split(dfhour$Precip,dfhour$STATION)
```

I can do an sapply function fine on this data, but I want to split it even further before using sapply.  I know that doing something like

```
sapply(split(split(dfhour$Precip, dfhour$STATION),dfhour$DATE),FUN=sum)
```

won't work because the output of a `split` function is a list, and the next `split` function would not be able to accept a list as an argument. Does anybody have any guidance on this issue? What other functions could help me get where I need to go?

Comment: While `data.table` is probably the right solution for your problem, I suggest you also learn `tapply`, which combines `sapply` and `split` into one step and can do split by two or more factors simultaneously, e.g. `tapply(data$Precip, list(data$STATION, data$DATE), sum)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're just looking for `aggregate`. If your data.frame is named "mydf":

```
> aggregate(Precip ~ ., mydf, sum)
   STATION  DATE Precip
1 COOP 310 -7788   0.39
2 COOP 499 -7122   1.14
3 COOP 310 -6654   0.69
4 COOP 499 -2350   0.96
```

Judging by the size of your data, though, you might want to use `data.table` instead:

```
> library(data.table)
data.table 1.8.8  For help type: help("data.table")
> DT <- data.table(mydf, key = "STATION,DATE")
> DT[, list(Precip = sum(Precip)), by = key(DT)]
    STATION  DATE Precip
1: COOP 310 -7788   0.39
2: COOP 310 -6654   0.69
3: COOP 499 -7122   1.14
4: COOP 499 -2350   0.96
```

---

#### Update, as per discussion in comments

Imagine your data were as follows (note the duplicated dates, but at different stations):

```
mydf <- structure(list(STATION = c("COOP 310", "COOP 310", "COOP 310",                 
     "COOP 310", "COOP 499", "COOP 499", "COOP 499", "COOP 499", "COOP 499",            
     "COOP 499", "COOP 499"), DATE = c(-7788L, -7788L, -6654L, -6654L,                  
     -7122L, -7122L, -7122L, -2350L, -2350L, -7788L, -7788L), Precip = c(0.24,          
     0.15, 0.59, 0.1, 0.64, 0.36, 0.14, 0.11, 0.85, 0.35, 0.17)), .Names = c("STATION", 
     "DATE", "Precip"), row.names = c(NA, 11L), class = "data.frame")
mydf
#     STATION  DATE Precip
# 1  COOP 310 -7788   0.24
# 2  COOP 310 -7788   0.15
# 3  COOP 310 -6654   0.59
# 4  COOP 310 -6654   0.10
# 5  COOP 499 -7122   0.64
# 6  COOP 499 -7122   0.36
# 7  COOP 499 -7122   0.14
# 8  COOP 499 -2350   0.11
# 9  COOP 499 -2350   0.85
# 10 COOP 499 -7788   0.35
# 11 COOP 499 -7788   0.17
```

Both alternatives presented will generate sums for the combinations of "STATION" and "DATE". Here's the `data.table` process and result:

```
DT <- data.table(mydf, key = "STATION,DATE")
DT[, list(Precip = sum(Precip)), by = key(DT)]
#     STATION  DATE Precip
# 1: COOP 310 -7788   0.39
# 2: COOP 310 -6654   0.69
# 3: COOP 499 -7788   0.52
# 4: COOP 499 -7122   1.14
# 5: COOP 499 -2350   0.96
```

Comment: This seems like a possible answer, but one issue may complicate it: in my million lines of this data, the DATE values will be duplicated eventually by different STATIONs. If it rained on June 17, 1995 at both Station 1, and Station 2, this aggregate function would combine the precipitation values into one `SUM`, rather than keeping the DATE*STATION value unique.

Comment: Can I aggregate based on Station Name without doing a sum function? Just group them based on station, then send them to an `AGGREGATE` function which sums by datexstation?

Comment: @user2332986, it's late where I am, so deciphering your follow-up questions is slow for me right now. Sorry! Can you just update your question with a minimal example that illustrates the problem case you foresee?

Comment: There could be this scenario for two data points: (1) Station A recorded 0.55 mm of rain on June 5, 1985 (UNIX timestamp of 5634). Station B could also have recorded, say, 0.35 mm of rain on June 5, 1985 (UNIX timestamp of 5634 as well). I do not want to include these two values in the same `SUM` instance because they are at different stations, even if they occurred at the same time. Does that make sense?

Comment: @user2332986, then you misunderstand the output above. This will use the unique combination of station *and* date. They won't be in the same `sum`.

Comment: @user2332986, I've added an example that I hope would address your concerns.

Comment: Worked very well! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

"Upwards of 1.5 million rows" combined with a simple split-apply-combine suggests `data.table` is the perfect tool for your problem.

I think you'd want something like:

```
DT[,sum(Precip),by="STATION,DATE"]
```

Where `DT` is the `data.table` form of your `data.frame`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto Yes you did :-)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the nested `splits`. You just need to provide a single "split" argument that captures the crossed levels, perhaps using the `interaction` function.

```
tapply( statfrm$Precip, interaction(statfrm$STATION, statfrm$DATE) , sum) 
#----------------
COOP-310.-7788 COOP-499.-7788 COOP-310.-7122 COOP-499.-7122 COOP-310.-6654 
          0.39             NA             NA           1.14           0.69 
COOP-499.-6654 COOP-310.-2350 COOP-499.-2350 
            NA             NA           0.96
```

You can also use a split-sapply strategy to get a similar answer and in your cas the zero values may be more appropriate than the NA's you get with tapply:

```
 sapply(split(statfrm$Precip, interaction(statfrm$STATION, statfrm$DATE) ), sum) 
#-------
COOP-310.-7788 COOP-499.-7788 COOP-310.-7122 COOP-499.-7122 COOP-310.-6654 
          0.39           0.00           0.00           1.14           0.69 
COOP-499.-6654 COOP-310.-2350 COOP-499.-2350 
          0.00           0.00           0.96
```

As far as display of this vector, I sometimes wrap as.matrix around a vector to getting to display "downward":

```
as.matrix(sapply(split(statfrm$Precip, interaction(statfrm$STATION, statfrm$DATE) ), sum))
#_________________
               [,1]
COOP-310.-7788 0.39
COOP-499.-7788 0.00
COOP-310.-7122 0.00
COOP-499.-7122 1.14
COOP-310.-6654 0.69
COOP-499.-6654 0.00
COOP-310.-2350 0.00
COOP-499.-2350 0.96
```

Comment: sapply has of class "numeric", am I right? How do I possibly convert this to something I can use for further operations? Say something like  with column1: STATION, column2: DATE, column 3: output of sapply SUM. Thanks again for your answer, it worked just fine assuming I can get past this last hurdle.

Comment: The `aggregate`function delivers its results that way. The `interaction` function creates a single-dimensional vector, so may not meet your goals.